# TCP Port open issue

Tags: networking

TCP port 5055 is closed when host is connected via WiFi. The same port is open when connected via Ethernet. How to open the port when connected via WiFi?

Comment: The networking layer (Ethernet/Wifi) and the transport layer (TCP) don't care about each other at all, so this must be related to the configuration of the application that provides the service on TCP port 5055 (or the configuration of the firewall if any). Could you please specify the network topology between the client and server, what application we're dealing with and how it's configured?

Answer (score 1):

You bound the application on the IP address of Ethernet card. You should bind it on 0.0.0.0 IP address which is accessible from any IP address.